# Java, how to continue running while ServerSocket.accept() takes in clients?

Tags: java

I am trying to make a multiplayer game where many calculations are done on the server with multiple clients. How could I have my server listen for new clients, while calculating for the game. Everything I have tried pauses the entire program while it runs ServerSocket.accept(). Is there any way around this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either the game loop or `ServerSocket.accept()` should be handled in its own [`Thread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html), while the other runs in the main thread.

Comment: I added put my code in like this, but the second one never runs. 'public static void main(String[] args){
new Thread(new computations());
new Thread(new acceptingClients());
}'

Comment: You need to call `start()` on your threads. They will then spin up a thread that will execute `run()` in your [`Runnable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) classes.

Comment: Wait, never mind. It was caused by another issue. Thank you!